# Способы оплаты без ухода с сайта

Tags: платежи, webmoney, шлюз

Здравствуйте

Существуют ли способы оплаты без ухода с сайта ?
Знаю только об интерфейсе X20 Webmoney.
А какие еще есть, особенно интересуют оплата через платёжные шлюзы, осуществляющие приём банковских карт.

Спасибо.

Comment: Чтобы была возможность оплачивать без ухода с сайта, нужен SSL сертификат на домен. И есть много систем оплат, которые имеют API для оплаты кредитной картой.